# Use R to insert df into SQL server, overwrite elements with same primary keys

Tags: sql, r, r-dbi

I have an existing table in SQL. I want to insert an R dataframe into this existing table.

I use the following code

```
dbWriteTable(con, "table_name", data_frame)
```

where `table_name` is the name of the SQL table and `data_frame` is my R data frame.

I want to overwrite the elements in my data frame which have the same primary keys as in my SQL table.

Comment: You won't achieve it with `dbWriteTable()`. Consider using manual SQL query.

Comment: did you try that passing `append = T` argument `dbWriteTable()` ? your code should look like `dbWriteTable(con, "table_name", data_frame,append=T)`

Comment: You'll likely need a bit of sqL to achieve this. Which database are you working on? To overwrite entries you'd need to create a temporary table. Something along the lines of: `dbWriteTable(con, "#temp", data_frame, temporary = TRUE); dbExecute(con, 'merge into table_name AS tgt using (select * from "#temp" ) as src on (tgt = src column specifcation) when matched update SET (column update list) WHEN NOT MATCHED then INSERT (column insert list)' )`. Note this is untested and you should always test this before running it on production tables (and update the 3 parenthesis' that are incomplete)

Comment: What you have described sounds like an `upsert` operation, search for that. Without knowing your specific DBMS, there is no sure way to resolve this, as most databases do it different (e.g., based on triggers or catching an insert-error). See [postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT), [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html), and [sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) for discussions.

Comment: @r2evans considering the phrase "SQL server" in the title, I presume one meant MS SQL.

Comment: You're probably correct. I've seen questions with "SQL server" referring to a server running some SQL database (sort of akin to "I'm running a marathon this weekend" ... "oh really? how long is the race?"). Not everybody is aware of the fact that "DBMS != DBMS", where the different dialects (of ANSI SQL-99 or such) can mean all the difference. Perhaps I'm just being too jaded or cautious :-)

Comment: And what's with the "marathon" joke? I googled it, but seems it's too ancient to show up in search results... :) Never heard.

Comment: @MaksimKuzmin, perhaps it's just my experience. A marathon is (by definition) 26 miles and 385 yards (aka 42.195km), but too many times when I've told a non-runner my plans, they ask how far it is; I believe they confuse "marathon" with "some long running race" where "long" is subjective, often anything over a couple of miles. (There are, of course, "half-marathons", which are well-defined, and "ultra-marathons", which are less-well defined.) My connection to this question was merely that not everybody associates "a sql server" with "SQL Server" the commercial product. Weak joke, perhaps. :-)